# VHDL _ TO_INTEGER

Tags: vhdl, quartus, vga

I'm confused about a problem I have in VHDL.

I make one `VGA_display_ characters`, so I wanna convert some `std_logic_vectors` into integer by `to_integer` unsigned, then I wanna recuperate, 
in this way I can't use those libraries in the same time.

`ieee.std_logic_arith.all` and `ieee.numeric_std.all`
The error given by quartus:

> (Error (10621): VHDL Use Clause error at interface.vhd(34): more than one Use Clause imports a declaration of simple name "unsigned" -- none of the declarations are directly visible
>   Error (10784): HDL error at syn_arit.vhd(26): see declaration for object "unsigned"
>   bellow my code :

[to_integer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGf4h.png)

[conv_std_logic_vector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeC8g.png)

Comment: The use clauses for std_logic_arith and numeric_std both would make declarations for type unsigned visible *except* IEEE Std 1076-2008 12.4 Use clauses,  para 8 " c) Potentially visible declarations that have the same designator and that are not covered by case b) are not made directly visible unless each of them is either an enumeration literal specification or the declaration of a subprogram."  The simple solution is to use one package or the other and without a [mcve] it looks like you're trying to use std_logic_unsigned anyway, you may be able to delete both bothersome use clauses.

Comment: Pictures of snippets or even complete code don't comprise (with the error message) a [mcve]. Someone could want to check an answer or future readers may not understand the solution and may want reproduce it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My advice is: don't use `ieee.std_logic_arith`. It's proprietary (not officially part of VHDL) and causes far, far more problems than it solves.

Use only `numeric_std` and you can do everything you need:

`to_integer(unsigned(X))` and `to_integer(signed(X))`, where `X` is an `std_logic_vector`.

To convert back in the other direction:

`std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(K, N))` and `std_logic_vector(to_signed(K, N))` where `K` is the integer to convert and `N` is the number of bits.

Comment: but i wanna convert to std_logic_vector again

Comment: I have updated my answer to include conversion back in the other direction.

Comment: You forgot about numeric_std_unsigned. Its part of VHDL 2008 standard and allows direct conversion of slv to integer and back `myint <= to_integer(slv)` and `myslv <= to_slv(myint, myslv'length)`

Comment: @Tricky Good point. Am I right to assume `numeric_std_unsigned` and `numeric_std_signed` cannot be used simultaneously, so you are limited to one type of (signed/unsigned) arithmetic per design unit? Do they support multiplication?

Comment: You are right, because numeric_std_signed does not exist. numeric_std_unsigned has all the same functionality as numeric_std, with slv instead of unsigned.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering