# VHDL arrays indexing

Tags: vhdl

I have a problem with arrays indexing:
I declare:

```
type matriz_fc is array (0 to 3) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
signal fils : matriz_fc;
signal filp, filf : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
signal i_p, i_f: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
fils <= ("0001", "0010", "0100", "1000");
```

And I try to get an 4 bits vector:
    filf <= fils(to_integer(unsigned(i_p)));

But It's marked as some errors:
Error: multiple declarations of ‘unsigned’ included via multiple use clauses; none are made directly visible
Error: type error near ‘unsigned(i_p)’; expected type ‘unsigned’
Error: formal ’arg’ has no actual or default value
Error: indexed name prefix type ‘integer’ is not an array type

Comment: Provide a [mcve].  One of the errors is caused by having two use clauses in the same declarative region making two declarations with the name `unsigned` visible. (The result is neither is visible).  You could remove one of the use clauses (and I vote for std_logic_arith because you use the to_integer function from package numeric_std) or use selected names (with the library and package names as a suffix).  (Really, get rid of one of the use clauses.

Comment: See [VHDL_TO_INTEGER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59058126/vhdl-to-integer).

Comment: This error usually occurs when you include both std_logic_arith and numeric_std packages. std_logic_arith is not a VHDL standard package so should be deleted.

Answer (score -1):

I ran the code that wrote above as it is in my Vivado 2019.1 simulator and I am getting no errors. Check the output in the image below. It might be possible that there is some error in the libraries that you are using. Always use numeric_std. And I also hope that you are writing this statement after the 'begin' of your architecture.
fils <= ("0001", "0010", "0100", "1000");
[output snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MELj4.png)